# Spring boot doesn't map folder requests to `index.html` files

Tags: java, static, spring-boot

I've got `static` folder with following structure:

> index.html
>   docs/index.html

Spring Boot correctly maps requests `/` to `index.html`. But it doesn't map `/docs/` request to `/docs/index.html` (`/docs/index.html` request works correctly).

How to map folder/subfolder requests to appropriate `index.html` files?

Comment: Does the view controller mapping I suggested answer your question? If so, please accept it. Otherwise please clarify your problem and I'll be happy to update my answer.

Answer (score 26):

You can manually add a view controller mapping to make this work:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomWebMvcConfigurerAdapter extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/docs").setViewName("redirect:/docs/");
        registry.addViewController("/docs/").setViewName("forward:/docs/index.html");
    super.addViewControllers(registry);
    }
}
```

The first mapping causes Spring MVC to send a redirect to the client if `/docs` (without trailing slash) gets requested. This is necessary if you have relative links in `/docs/index.html`. The second mapping forwards any request to `/docs/` internally (without sending a redirect to the client) to the `index.html` in the `docs` subdirectory.

Comment: Works with nested subfolders as well: `registry.addViewController("/v2/docs").setViewName("redirect:/v2/docs/");` and `registry.addViewController("/v2/docs/").setViewName("forward:/v2/docs/index.html");`

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I've updated it to make it work with [**Spring 5** / **Spring Boot 2**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59052438/1654265)

Comment: Is there a way to make this work with all subfolders, not just named ones?

Comment: Yes, you can add a mapping but let's say you generated a static blog page with Hugo (https://gohugo.io/) and are serving it from the Spring static folder. Hugo has an index.html for every blog entry. So if your blog has 100 pages, you'll need 100 mappings. Also, every time you add a new blog item you'll have to add a mapping for that. Not very convenient.

Answer (score 8):

After Java 8 introduced [Default Methods in Interfaces](https://www.baeldung.com/java-static-default-methods), `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` has been **deprecated in Spring 5 / Spring Boot 2**.

Using it will now raise [the warning](https://www.baeldung.com/web-mvc-configurer-adapter-deprecated):

> The type WebMvcConfigurerAdapter is deprecated

Hence, to make [@hzpz's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29969014/1654265) work again, we need to change it as follows:

```java
@Configuration
public class CustomWebMvcConfigurer implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/docs").setViewName("redirect:/docs/");
        registry.addViewController("/docs/").setViewName("forward:/docs/index.html");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not Spring Boot mapping to index.html it's the servlet engine (it's a welcome page). There's only one welcome page (per the spec), and directory browsing is not a feature of the containers.

Comment: this explains the problem but doesn't suggests a solution so I can't accept this answer

Comment: I don't think there is a solution other than you writing your own directory browser servlet handler. I can suggest that if you like?

Answer (score 3):

This one will always try to match `requestPath + /index.html` if static resource is not found:

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceResolverChain;

@Configuration
public class ResourceHandlerConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  static class IndexFallbackResourceResolver extends PathResourceResolver{
    @Override
    protected Resource resolveResourceInternal(HttpServletRequest request, String requestPath,
        List<? extends Resource> locations, ResourceResolverChain chain) {
      Resource resource = super.resolveResourceInternal(request, requestPath, locations, chain);
      if(resource==null){
        //try with /index.html
        resource = super.resolveResourceInternal(request, requestPath + "/index.html", locations, chain);
      }
      return resource;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry
        .setOrder(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
        .addResourceHandler("/**")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
        //first time resolved, that route will always be used from cache
        .resourceChain(true)
        .addResolver(new IndexFallbackResourceResolver());
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Spring boot show index.html by default.

but index.html should be 
in
/resource/static or 
/public

example:

```
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-static
```