# Spring Boot 2 index.html not loaded automatically from subdirectory mapped as static resource

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

I have a Maven module containing my Angular 6 application, and at build it is packaged in a jar at `META-INF/resources/admin/ui`.

My Spring Boot 2 application has a dependency to the frontend Maven module and when building it includes the frontend library as well. However, if I access `http://localhost:8080/admin/ui/` it downloads an empty ui file, but if I access `http://localhost:8080/admin/ui/index.html` then it displays the Angular application.

If I package the frontend application at `META-INF/resources/` then `http://localhost:8080/` will display the Angular application correctly, but I want the context of the frontend application to start from `/admin/ui`. The Spring Boot application does not have any custom mappings, it is just annotated with

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {...})
@Import({...})
```

Is there a configuration property that I am missing?

I appreciate the help.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28437314/spring-boot-doesnt-map-folder-requests-to-index-html-files and that question has better answers than this one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need all those annotations to make it working... I would recommend please remove those which are not added purposely by you..!!

To serve your static page on different path than the main context, here is a work-around..!!

Create another simple controller class like below..

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class Home {

    @RequestMapping(path = "/")
    public String getHome(){
        return "redirect:/admin/ui/"; 
      // make sure no space between colon (:) and endpoint name (/admin/ui)
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/admin/ui/" )
    public  String getAdminUi(){
        return "/index.html";
      // your index.html built by angular should be in resources/static folder
      // if it is in resources/static/dist/index.html,
      // change the return statement to "/dist/index.html"
    }

}
```

And, notice here, I have marked the class as `@Controller` not the `@RestController` so if you mark it to `@RestController` or try to do the same in any existing `@RestController` you would not achieve it easily. So, it's no harm to create another class like above.

Benefit of this way is, it don't destroy your existing mappings.. also the context path is not changes, so no need to bother about your other endpoint paths. They all shall work as before.

Hope this helped!!

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was trying to avoid writing an extra controller for this purpose, and was hoping to find a simpler solution in terms of adding something in a Spring configuration property, but I found a 2-year old "bug" report to the Spring team with the same problem as this and they rejected it stating that if a "welcome page" is located somewhere other than "/" then it is a resource, not a Welcome page, and must be treated as such and the only solution is the one mentioned above.

Comment: However, since my use case is just serving a static index.html without any rendering, a more simpler solution was to override the WebMvcConfigurer#addViewControllers method and add something like 
`registry.addViewController("/admin/ui").setViewName("/admin/ui/index.html");`,or if a redirect is needed then `registry.addRedirectViewController("/admin/ui", "/admin/ui/index.html");`. Downside is that `/admin/ui` and `/admin/ui/` are two different mappings, so I need to add two mappings for the same resource, but it fixes the problem. I upvoted your answer since it will fix the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for the briefing !! That's why I mentioned in my answer that it is a work-around way..!! And I really appreciate the efforts you put in to understand the things in more detail. Keep it up. I'm up voting your answer too as readers can found helpful information from this..!! Cheers.. :)