# Sprint Boot Web Application with Maven not returning HTML page

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have created a simple Spring Boot Web App using Maven .Tried to return a HTML page on hitting the / page but its not returning throwing White Label Error Page.

> My Main Class:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ProductLaunchReportingApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProductLaunchReportingApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

> Controller :

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
//@ResponseBody
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String viewHome() {
        return "home";
    }

}
```

> Application Properties:

```
server.port=9991
```

> home.html :(location:src/main/resources/static)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello From Home Page</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show your pom.xml and in which package ProductLaunchReportingApplication and HomeController are

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51555158/6446770 see this for detailed answer.. also read comments for better understanding.

Comment: things under `src/main/resources/static` aren't resolved using a ViewResolver but rather directly. So `/home.html` will work. If that isn't what you want, include something like Thymeleaf and place the files in `src/main/resources/templates` instead of `static`.

Answer (score 2):

When you are using Spring Boot. The only thing you need to get it working is this dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

And you need to add your html file in resources/templates/home.html

Answer (score 1):

Put your HTML at `src/main/resources/templates/home.html` and it will work.

---

You can follow [this link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/) for more help.

Comment: @RestController will return only the String "home" not the html page.

Comment: Updated my answer.